# How do I select the next "n" elements starting from the current element in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

How do I select the next "n" elements starting from the current element? What I mean is...

```
 $(this).attr(...);
```

I want to do this "n" times. For the example of n=4:

```
$(this).attr(...);
$(this).next().attr(...);
$(this).next().next().attr(...);
$(this).next().next().next().attr(...);
```

or perhaps do it in a loop:

```
for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    $(this).next().attr(...);
}
```

How can I do this? Is there a way I can do this by selecting the next "n" elements or in a loop?

Comment: Why the heck was this downvoted? This is worded well, and it's an usual problem.

Comment: Agreed. Two down-votes and no explanation. People who down-vote should leave a reason why. This seems like a perfectly reasonable question to me.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

This should work:

```
$(this).nextAll().slice(0,4).attr(…)
```

**Update:**

This will work, too:

```
$(this).nextAll("*:lt(4)").attr(…)
```

Comment: would the '0' in slice() be $(this)?

Comment: no, because before that you call `.nextAll()` this doesn't contain the element itself

Comment: @Hristo - If you need the original one as well, you could call `$(this).nextAll().andSelf()...`.

Comment: @jigfox... is .slice() inclusive or exclusive on the parameters?

Comment: @Hristo: the first parameter is inclusive, the second exclusive

Answer (score 10):

[the `nextAll` method](http://api.jquery.com/nextAll) selects the following siblings of an element, optionally filtered by a selector.  You could then follow that with a `slice` to restrict to a smaller n.

Answer (score 0):

`$(this).slice(start_index, end_index)` will select a portion of your selection. You could keep track of your current index in the loop and then apply the `.slice(cur_index, cur_index+n)` function on the original set when you hit your condition.