# How can I select next 3 siblings of an element which is randomly placed?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to select the next 3 siblings of a grid of divs on a board.
I was thinking of using nextUntil() but as the id's of these siblings are also randomly placed upon load so they are not set. I don't know how to do it.
I have tried using some operators:

```
$((".Jim").attr('id')).nextUntil($( ".Jim" ).attr('id') * 1 + (3)).css( "background-color", "red" );
```

Jim is a game character with a class of Jim.
He is randomly placed in one of the grid divs on a gameboard.
I want to change the style of the next three divs(squares) so that the player knows they can only move to those squares.
Next until seems like a good way to go but I cannot figure out how to specify until the 3rd sibling.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Do you mean 3 first siblings ?

Comment: `$((".Jim").attr('id'))` this is incorrect, it must be `$("#"+$(".Jim").attr('id'))`.

Comment: Can you show us an original html part in you question..

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I select the next "n" elements starting from the current element in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3461863/how-do-i-select-the-next-n-elements-starting-from-the-current-element-in-jquer)

Comment: Thanks guys for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select the next 3 elements after the div with the class "Jim" using [`nextAll()`](https://api.jquery.com/nextAll/) and [`slice()`](https://api.jquery.com/slice/) like this:

```js
$(".Jim").nextAll().slice(0,3).css("background-color", "red");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="Jim">
  Jim
</div>
<div>
  1
</div>
<div>
  2
</div>
<div>
  3
</div>
<div>
  4
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Matthias, it worked!!
what if I needed the 10th 20th and 30th sibling?
does it take the same method or something else?

Comment: @Johnroiste You can use the same method - e.g. for the 10th sibling it's $(".Jim").nextAll().slice(9,10).css("background-color", "red");

Comment: Thank you I'll give it a try!